# Prove that $u$ is weak solution to Burgers equation with initial condition $u_0$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

I want to prove that 
$$ u(t,x)=\begin{cases} 0 &\text{if } x\leq 0 \\ x/t &\text{if } 0\leq x \leq t \\ 1 &\text{if } x\geq t \end{cases} $$
is a weak solution to $ u_t + uu_x =0 $ with initial condition $$u_0 (x) = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{ if } x \geq 0 \\ 0 &\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$
that is, to prove that 
$$  \int_{Q_T} \phi_t u + \phi_x \frac{u^2}{2} \ dxdt =-\int_{\mathbb{R}} u_0(x)\phi(0,x)\ dx\qquad \forall \phi\in C_0^1 ([0,T)\times\mathbb{R})$$
where $Q_T=[0,T]\times \mathbb{R}$.

I am stuck in the computations, and help is welcome. Thank in advance!
EDIT: I don't know how to deal with the next integral
$$  \int_{[0,T]}\int_{[0,t]} \frac{x}{t}\phi_t + \frac{x^2}{2t^2}\phi_x\ \ dxdt $$

Comment: Exchange the order of integration, then integrate by parts.

Comment: Doing IBP, what do I call $u$ and what $dv$?

Comment: For the answer to your IBP question, [please study this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_solution#A_concrete_example). But I should have looked closer at what you wrote down. That is not the definition of a weak solution. In fact, full solutions would not satisfy that equation, even for a well-behaved $u_0$. For any weak solution, the LH side should be $0$, while the RH side is not $0$ for general $\phi$.

Comment: I found that definition of weak solution to $u_t + uu_x =0$ in every text I looked.

Comment: Obviously you only looked at this one single example, otherwise you would have comprehended my mistake, which is that since you are looking at a sharp lower bound, compact support does not require $\phi$ to be $0$ at $0$ (I'm used to doing this on open intervals, $\phi$ must be $0$ in both directions.) The RH side is the result of the $\left.\overset {\phantom{.}} \phi u  \right|_0^T$ term from integration by parts of $\int_0^T\phi u_t\,dt$ not being $0$. That is indeed the condition for a weak solution of this problem.

Comment: But you need to split the integral into $$\int_{Q_T} \phi_t u\, dtdx + \int_{Q_T} \phi_x \frac{u^2}2\, dxdt$$ Then the choices for the "u" and "v" of IBP for each are obvious.

Comment: You are right, but look where I have the specific doubt: (next comment)

Comment: For the case $0\leq x\leq t$, the solution is $u=x/t$. Now, let's take a look at the first integral you wrote previously, $$\int_{[0,t]}\int_{[0,T]}( x/t) \phi_t (x,t)\ dt \ dx$$, applying IBP, yields $$ \int_{[0,t]} \left[ (x/t)\phi (x,t) \vert_{[t=T,t=0]} + \int_{[0,T]}(x/tˆ2) \phi (x,t) \right]\ dx$$ the problem is when I solve  $x/t\phi (x,t) \vert_{[t=T,t=0]}$, because it appears a zero dividing...

Comment: When $t = 0$ you also have $x = 0$, so $x /t$ is indeterminant. Since it is an isolated point, you can assign $x/t$ any real value without changing the integral, so the integral equation still holds.

Comment: Wow, its true, i should notice that... Thank you very much Paul! +1